# How to hide a message from data binding when changes in input box

Tags: angular, html, firebase

I am Completely new to Angular. I am working on Angular 4 and I stuck in a position where I have two input boxes for email and password. If Email and password does not match it shows a message Email or password incorrect which is written in data binding. Now user clicks on input box to change email or password that message should disappear.I hope someone will help me to get this.

Here is my html

```
 <form name="userform" method="post" #formCtrl="ngForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email" id="input" (click)="abcd()" placeholder="Email" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.password" id="input" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="margin-bottom: 20px" (click)="signInWithEmail()" [disabled]="formCtrl.form.invalid">
              Login with Email
            </button>
          </div>
          <label>{{message}}</label>
 </form>
```

and Angular code

```
signInWithEmail() {
this.authService.createUser(this.user.email, this.user.password)
  .then((res) => {
    this.signIntoDB();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    if (err.code == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
      this.authService.signIn(this.user.email, this.user.password)
        .then((res) => {

          this.accountEmailFirebaseService.getEmailParentId(res.uid).then((parentId: string) => {
            this.shared.saveAuth(res.uid, res.email, res.providerData[0].providerId, parentId)
            this.accser.saveAccountWithEmail(this.user.email, res.uid)
              .subscribe((data: string) => {
                this.addLoginInfo(data)
              }, error => () => { }, () => { });
          });


        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.message = error.message;
          console.log(error);

        });
    }
    else {
      this.message = "Email or Password Incorrect";
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like the message to disappear when you click on either the email or password fields, you can bind a click event to your input boxes using `(click)`, like so:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" (click)="message = ''" [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email" id="input" (click)="abcd()" placeholder="Email" required>

<input type="password" class="form-control" (click)="message = ''" [(ngModel)]="user.password" id="input" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
```

This will tell the input box that upon clicking into that input box, `message` will be cleared. You can fill in `(click)="..."` as you see fit; it can be a function or a simple variable assignment like what I showed in the example code above.

If you'd like more information on binding events like `(click)` here's a useful link to help you get started: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Good luck!